# Time series resampling with column of type object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, resampling

Good evening,

I want to resample on an irregular time series with column of type object but it does not work

Here is my sample data:

```
Actual start date   Ingredients                 NumberShortage
2002-01-01          LEVOBUNOLOL HYDROCHLORIDE   1
2006-07-30          LEVETIRACETAM               1
2008-03-19          FLAVOXATE HYDROCHLORIDE     1
2010-01-01          LEVOTHYROXINE SODIUM        1
2011-04-01          BIMATOPROST                 1
```

I tried to re-sample my data frame daily but it does not work with my code which is as follows:

```
df3 =  df1.resample('D', on='Actual start date').sum()
```

and here is what it gives:

```
Actual start date   NumberShortage
2002-01-01          1
2002-01-02          0
2002-01-03          0
2002-01-04          0
2002-01-05          0
```

and what I want as a result:

```
 Actual start date  Ingredients                 NumberShortage
    2002-01-01      LEVOBUNOLOL HYDROCHLORIDE   1
    2002-01-02      NAN                         0
    2002-01-03      NAN                         0
    2002-01-04      NAN                         0
    2002-01-05      NAN                         0
```

Any ideas?

###### details on the data

So I use an excel file which contains several attributes before it is a csv file (this file can be downloaded from this site web https://www.drugshortagescanada.ca/search?perform=0 ) then I group by 'Actual start date' and 'Ingredients'to obtain 'NumberShortage'

and here is the source code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Data/Data.xlsx")

df = df.dropna(how='any')   

df = df.groupby(['Actual start date','Ingredients']).size().reset_index(name='NumberShortage')
```

finally after having applied your source code here is the eureur which gives me :

[image]

and here is the sample excel file :

```
        Brand name             Company Name  Ingredients Actual start date 
        ACETAMINOPHEN          PHARMASCIENCE INC ACETAMINOPHEN CODEINE 2017-03-23
PMS-METHYLPHENIDATE ER         PHARMASCIENCE INC METHYLPHENIDATE 2017-03-28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rather need to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) using [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) as a source of new dates, and the time series as temporary index:

```
df['Actual start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual start date'])

(df
 .set_index('Actual start date')
 .reindex(pd.date_range(df['Actual start date'].min(),
                        df['Actual start date'].max(), freq='D'))
 .fillna({'NumberShortage': 0}, downcast='infer')
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
          index                Ingredients  NumberShortage
0    2002-01-01  LEVOBUNOLOL HYDROCHLORIDE               1
1    2002-01-02                        NaN               0
2    2002-01-03                        NaN               0
3    2002-01-04                        NaN               0
4    2002-01-05                        NaN               0
...         ...                        ...             ...
3373 2011-03-28                        NaN               0
3374 2011-03-29                        NaN               0
3375 2011-03-30                        NaN               0
3376 2011-03-31                        NaN               0
3377 2011-04-01                BIMATOPROST               1

[3378 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: indeed, I read an excel file by `df = pd.read_excel("Data/d.xlsx")`
already treated and when I use this code it gives as error: `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`

Comment: so you have duplicated dates in the input?

Comment: even I removed the duplication with this code but nothing worked : `df4 = df.sort_values('Actual start date').drop_duplicates('Ingredients',keep='last')`

Comment: Can you provide a constructor of a minimal example for which it doesn't work?

Comment: yes of course in the next post I will put the piece of code

Comment: I put above or it does not work

Comment: don't post details as answer, you should rather [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71752997/edit) the question ;) Also, don't get us to download data, just provide a **small** subset of the data that produces the error (just of few lines) and the output you would expected

Comment: sorry I didn't know, I edited the post with a small sample of my excel file